# unirest.post is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, response, unirest

I am trying to call my api through `Node.js` using `Unirest`.

I am getting an error which is :

> unirest.post is not a function

My code is as follows:

```
var unirest = require(['unirest'], function (unirest) { });
unirest.post('http://localhost:8080/country')
  .headers({ 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
  .send(json_query)
  .end(function (response) {
    alert(response.body);
  });
```

Can someone explain me why does it occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. So, with the additional information, you need to use async imports as per link you provided:

```
require(['foo'], function (foo) {
    // foo is available here...
});
// foo isn't available here
```

And in your specific case,

```
require(['unirest'], function (unirest) {
    unirest.post('http://localhost:8080/country') // etc.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a vanilla require statement, copied & pasted from the docs:

```
var unirest = require('unirest');
```

Comment: I had tried using simple require statement.But I was getting [MODULE NAME ... HAS NOT BEEN LOADED YET FOR CONTEXT: ...](https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded) error. So according to their solution provided I had changed my code in this way and it worked.Then I am encountering this error message.

Comment: Wait, is the `require` not Node's native `require`, but the `require` from require.js?

Comment: Yes **require** is from require.js not from Node's native require